# OCR in Jira, how to get text information from screenshots

Tags: ocr, jira, image-text

we use jira as our ITSM tool. Often our end users send screenhosts in the tickets and we need to manually retype the text from it (exceptions, urls...). It would be great if we could automatically extract the text from images in jira by some OCR tool. But so far I was not able to find any simple solution. Do you know something?

I tried some OCR Tools which works fine. But I would like to have something directly in Jira so I do not have to switch into another app.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the app **[AI SnapRead for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1231804/ai-snapread-for-jira)**

It is an AI based OCR for images in Jira Attachments. It is based on Azure AI.

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).

Comment: Note that you are *clearly* affiliated to the product you linked, as can be seen from both your username and your profile. You need to include an **explicit** disclaimer that you have this affiliation.